# How would someone generate documentation from an Entity Framework code first mapping context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

I would like to generate a document from the Entity Framework code-first context class. The documentation would generate an object reference model and how it is mapped to the database. How would one go about doing this as part of the build process?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?